# rails 3.2 link a subdomain to a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saas, subdomain

Update: rewritten question a bit. Trying to route my subdomains like below

- login.app.ltd
- user1.app.ltd
- user2.app.ltd
- signup.app.ltd

Using

- Rails 3.2
- Devise

To no avail tried several tutorials blog posts, anyone knows a working example for this? 
Really stuck on this :(

this is my routes now:

```
 match '', to: 'frontend#index', constraints: lambda { |r| r.subdomain.present? && ( r.subdomain != 'www') }
  #match '' => 'home#index', :constraints => { :subdomain => 'login' }


  constraints :subdomain => /^(?!signup\b)(\w+)/ do
    root :to => "frontend#index"
  end

  root :to => "frontend#index"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [RailsApps project](http://railsapps.github.com/) offers a complete example app showing how to use subdomains:

[Rails Tutorial for Subdomains with Devise](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-subdomains.html)

Did you take a look at that?

**config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => :show
constraints(Subdomain) do
  match '/' => 'profiles#show'
end
root :to => "home#index"
```

**lib/subdomain.rb**

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    case request.subdomain
    when 'www', '', nil
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Daniel I think i have this is for a project im no longer working on currently , maybe in near future I will start from scratch then and look at your example then thx.

Answer (score 1):

Ok with some help managed to get it working

One should do:

```
 constraints subdomain: 'login' do
devise_scope :user do
  root to: 'sessions#new'
end
```

end